# get rid of artifacts (fluid)

Tags: texturing, fluid-simulation, artifacts

how to get rid of black spots (artifacts). I'm using gradient animation on water simulation 2.80 (old fluid sim.) But, when i play animation on viewport, there is no issue of black spots.
Video https://vk.com/blender_3d?z=video-947906_456245040%2F97f5a90e1d430fd5c8%2Fpl_post_-947906_987830
[image]

2nd link for video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OChLqpIZiNyb-Mn2C6QW5Y06L3JnPBym/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The black spots seem to be the fluid intersecting the surface of the background. Try moving the fluid up. Also there is no reason to use the old fluid simulation system. Mantaflow is superior. I would recommend using current version and the new fluid simulation system. It will give you better results.

Comment: But, when i play animation on viewport, there is no issue of black spots. about new fluid simualtion, i really dont like it. its has very low amount of funtions to editm, rather the old liquid system. I try to make it on 2.83, but can't get any results.

Comment: You provide no info about your setup at all so it's very hard to guess... I guess it might be  z-fighting?.. Maybe your viewport clipping values are different from the camera clipping values.